# Storing Child Class Objects in the Same Container without loosing data?

Tags: c++, object, containers, parent-child, radix

So lets say I have a base class called Fruits,

```
class Fruit{

  public TYPE{ Apples, Oranges, Grapes, NoType };
  virtual int getType(){ return Fruit::TYPE::NoType; };
  virtual ~Fruits(){};

  virtual int randomFunc(){ return 991; };

}
```

And then lets say I have a child class called Apple,

```
class Apple : public Fruit{

  virtual int getType()override{ return Fruit::TYPE::Apples; };

  virtual int childFunc(){ return -1; };

}
```

Now, my question, is it possible to receive an object with the base class Fruits, and store various child objects in the same map/container without loosing the 'childFunc()' functionality, or any variables/functions not existent in the base? Ideally I'm trying to find something like,

```
int FruitStorage::addFruit( Fruit* f, int i ){

     this->fruitsMap[i] = *f; //I feel like receiving a base object will strip the child functionality. 
     return this->fruitsMap[i]->childFunc(); //I need to use the child functions after the object is stored.

}
```

Would it be possible to use templates for something like this? Is this a practice that's generally frowned upon? My issue with separate containers is that I need to track on a first-in-first-out basis.

Comment: See [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). You've already suffered it when you passed `Fruit` to `addFruit` by value, even before you got to placing it into a container. To preserve polymorphic behavior, you need to pass instances of `Fruit` (or its derived classes) around by (possibly smart) pointer.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to show that I'm receiving a pointer of a Fruit object.

Comment: You also forgot to show the declaration of `fruitsMap`. One line looks like it stores objects, but the very next line suggests it stores pointers. Which way is it?

Comment: My direct object I just mean the base class. If I receive the base class, and cast it as a base class (into the map/container), it will loose all the functionality of the child class.

Comment: Well, so don't. You claim you already know enough to avoid slicing when you pass the object by pointer - so then store it by pointer, too.

Comment: I would store it by pointer but the Fruits are non static objects and would likely go out of scope without fully transferring their data. Making future calls null.

Comment: Those objects will have to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79842/discussion-between-travis-truttschel-and-igor-tandetnik).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `std::shared_ptr<Fruit>` in your container. To see if you can rely on childFunct() you need to do a `dynamic_cast<Apple *>(fruit.get())` where fruit is a `std::shared_ptr<Fruit>`

Comment: If I'm parsing a lot of fruit (a large number of objects being generated), would dynamic_cast slow down the application?

Comment: In the code that purports to handle `Fruit` generically, why do you want to call a method that's specific to `Apple` and absent from `Fruit`?

Comment: Mainly because I thought it would be easier to have one 'addFruit' function that accepts various types of fruit, and still allows each individual type to perform and hold different functions. Then later, figure out what type it is (by using the virtual getType() function from the base class), and call the respective different functions.

Comment: So instead of `dynamic_cast`, do `if (myFruit->getType() == Fruit::Apples) static_cast<Apple*>(myFruit)->childFunc();`. Does this alleviate your performance concern?

Comment: I am curios t know what different functions means. There is the opportunity to have a virtual function there (with different implementation for each subclass')

Comment: Mainly because different fruit store different variables, as such, they have different functions for managing the different variables. However they all are Fruit.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I don't think doing an "if" followed by a static_cast will help with the performance; the only difference with the dynamic cast should be that it does an check on the type, so I would expect the performance to be the same, and dynamic cast is cleaner.  That said, if you don't know the type ahead of time, you may want to do a series of tests followed by a specialized static_cast for each (or better, hash the type).

Comment: `However they all are Fruit.` In what sense are they all `Fruit`, if they have no functionality at all in common? What makes an object a `Fruit`, exactly?

Comment: They all share the randomFunc(), and the Fruit class works to allow them all to be accepted as Fruit by various functions.